# Conditional choice between two values

Tags: plsql, conditional-statements, conditional-operator

I am wondering if there is a conditional selection between values in PL/SQL as there is the following in C-based languages: `[condition] ? [value1] : [value2]`.

I would like to use it in an update statement as such:

```
UPDATE [table] SET [field] = [condition] ? [value1] : [value2] WHERE [where clause];
```

I've already though of `DECODE`, but I would like to use it directly and not store its result in a variable and then use it in the update statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using the `CASE` statement

```
UPDATE [table]
SET [field] =
  CASE
    WHEN field2 = 'Y'
      THEN [value1]
    WHEN field2 = 'N'
      THEN [value2]
    ELSE 
  END;
```

Comment: You could also use DECODE if it's a simple condition:
UPDATE [table]
SET [field] = DECODE(field2,[value],[value when field2 = value],[value when field2 <> value])
WHERE [where clause];